# HDMI audio disappears when the TV is turned off and on

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, amd-radeon

I have a new HTPC build (it's running Windows 7 Ultimate x64) and it has a ATI Radeon 6450 as graphics card.

When I boot the PC, everything works fine. However, when the TV is turned off and then back on I notice there's no sound anymore. There are lots of other people who have this issue aswell. I've found [this workaround](http://www.avsforum.com/t/1068741/hdmi-audio-problem-after-powering-tv-off-and-on#post_15154620) however it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have the newest drivers (12.4). Someone said it was fixed in 9.1 but I still have the issue.

Comment: Maybe the default audio device is switched to an on-board audio, if you have it. Try disabling all other audio devices in device manager.

Comment: @haimg Unfortunately, it's not working. As seen in the screenshot (language is Dutch): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/84195929/hdmioutput.png (`niet aangesloten` means `not connected`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see this [thread](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=hdmi%20audio%20problem%20after%20powering%20tv%20off%20and%20on&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/353284-33-hdmi-audio-plugged-turning&ei=9lTYT9G8O9CrrAfY2dXyDw&usg=AFQjCNHIvoE7Bm0i319IuW1nFK81vLLHHA&cad=rja). It solves the issue for some user.

In short: The 12.4 drivers are buggy, revert to 12.3 until fixed drivers are released.

Comment: Thanks, seems it's an issue with 12.4. See [this thread](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/159106) for even more information. It also seems to be fixed in the [12.6 beta drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst126beta.aspx).

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu 12.04. Reverting the drivers from 12.4 to 12.3 solved the problem.